# canonical name to RDS instance

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation

I have different EC2 instances trying to access RDS instance. I want to upfront set RDS instance 'canonical name' within configuration file so that after deployment I don't need to make any changes to configuration files.

I have following questions:

1. Is there anyway, one can assign canonical name to a RDS instance within cloudformation template?
2. If above is not possible, can I setup dependency chain between EC2 creation and RDS instance (i.e. create RDS instance first, query it's name/ip and than create EC2 instance)

Thx

Answer (score 1):

The canonical name of an RDS instance will always be generated automatically by AWS, however the naming scheme is consistent.  The format of the name is:

```
<instance_name>.<arbitrary_string>.<region>.rds.amazonaws.com
```

The `arbitrary_string` section of the name is a string that uniquely identifies your AWS account. All RDS instances created within your account will use the same string identifier, so just grab that section from an existing RDS instance and you can piece together the full name based on the name you give the database and the region you launch it in.

If you want to have an easy to read/remember DNS name then you can always use [Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) to assign another name as an alias to this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I want to fully automate my deployment, do you think the arbitrary_string will remain same across multiple deployments? As far as Route 53 settings, do I have to have elastic IP to setup Route 53?

Comment: The arbitrary_string value shouldn't change within the confines of a single AWS account.  I've been using RDS for about 3 years now and it's never changed.  And no, you don't need to use an elastic IP to make use of Route 53. Route 53 is basically just Amazons DNS offering.  You can set up an alias or CNAME to point to your RDS instance very easily.  As another option you might want to consider simply using the AWS CLI to get the endpoint name of the instance you're interested in.  rds-describe-db-instances will do that.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I see, this might be an option to query db instance name before running your deployment and use it within chef cookbook. As you've suggested suppose if I want to have my website www.example.com point to an EC2 instance is it better to use Route 53 vs. Elastic IP and what would be better option?

Comment: You can't assign [Elastic IP's to RDS instances](http://serverfault.com/questions/589140/assign-elastic-ip-to-rds-instance). All Route 53 gives you is the ability to assign a more user-friendly DNS name to an RDS instance.